# jQuery, Ajax and REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, query-string

I've been attempting to refactor a fairly simple three or four page site to use a very lightweight MVC setup (probably overkill - but I thought I'd try it out for fun).

The site uses an `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
#allow various filetypes
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This allows me to grab the URL and run it through a router.  However, when trying to issue an Ajax request (via jQuery) - there is a query string being appended to the URL (dumped from PHP):

```
['key'] =>'2?_=1282088000558'
//should be:
['key]=>'2'
```

checking the $_SERVER array, I see that the value is recorded as REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING

This doesn't seem to be a problem with Javascript disabled, can anyone offer any insight on this problem? Is there a way of preventing jQuery from inserting this value, or should I just remove it in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there to *force* the browser to not get the request from cache, it's really doing this, using the timestamp to get a fresh request back from the server...it's for the browser's benefit though:

```
url + _= + (new Date()).getTime();
```

You can see [jQuery adding this here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L269):

```
if ( s.cache === false && type === "GET" ) {
  var ts = jQuery.now();

  // try replacing _= if it is there
  var ret = s.url.replace(rts, "$1_=" + ts + "$2");

  // if nothing was replaced, add timestamp to the end
  s.url = ret + ((ret === s.url) ? (rquery.test(s.url) ? "&" : "?") + "_=" + ts : "");
}
```

You can strip it off if you like by using `cache: true` in the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options or by using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is adding a random component to the query string in order to avoid the request to hit the browser/server cache.